# How to Group by all 12 months in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-1.3

I am using cakephp 1.3. I have date field in incomes table. I am trying to get total income per month in a loop. The following is my query.

```
$income_and_hst = $Income->find('all', array(
                            'fields' => array('SUM(Income.amount) as income', 
                                            'SUM(Income.hst_amount) as hst', 
                                            'MONTH(date) as month'),
                            'conditions' => array(
                                'Income.income_account_id' => array(1,2,3,4),
                                'Income.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
                                'Income.account_id' => $this->Session->read('Account.default_account'),
                                'Income.date >' => $starting_date,
                                'Income.date <' => $ending_date,
                                ),
                            'group' => 'MONTH(date)',
                            )
                        );
```

This gives me 5 months of income. Because the income were from 5 months. I need to show all 12 months even there is no income in other months. If there is no income i want 0 for that month.

Could someone give me a direction please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you cannot do that using that interface. You either need to dive into raw SQL (and a cross join), or add the missing months in the surrounding php code. I suggest the latter something like this should work (pseudocode, i don't remember php syntax):

```
for ($row in $income_and_hst) {
    $income_and_hst_all[$row['month']] = $row
}

for ($month = 1;$month <= 12; $month++) {
    if ($income_and_hst_all[$month] == nil) {
       $income_and_hst_all[$month] = Array (
           'income' => 0, 
           'hst' => 0, 
           'month' => $month
       )
    }
}
```